# Android: Custom layout with checkbox in list view instant change text color

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, checkbox

I have custom layout with a checkbox and 2 textViews.

I'm building another layout which include a listView. This listView lines should use the custom layout.

The problem is. I want to change the textViews color according to the checkbox state instantly: when i check/uncheck the color changes.
But the color changes only when I add another item...

My adapter code:

```
public class TodoAdapter2 extends ArrayAdapter<TodoTask>{

    Context context; 
    int layoutResourceId;    
    ArrayList<TodoTask> data = null;

    public TodoAdapter2(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<TodoTask> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View localView = convertView;
        todoHolder holder = null;
        if(localView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            localView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new todoHolder();
            holder.task = (TextView) localView.findViewById(R.id.taskName);
            holder.date = (TextView) localView.findViewById(R.id.taskDate);
            holder.status = (CheckBox) localView.findViewById(R.id.toDoChecked);
            localView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (todoHolder) localView.getTag();
        }

        TodoTask newTask = data.get(position);
        if(holder.status.isChecked()){
            holder.task.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            holder.date.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
        else{
            holder.task.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            holder.date.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }



        holder.task.setText(newTask.getTask());
        holder.date.setText(newTask.toStringDate());
        return localView;
    }

    class todoHolder{
        CheckBox status;
        TextView task;
        TextView date;
    }
}
```

My activity code:

```
public class TodoListManagerActivity extends Activity {
    private ArrayList<TodoTask> tasks;
    private ListView list;
    TodoAdapter2 ad;
    final int BROWSER_ACTIVATION_REQUEST = 2; // request code

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tasks = new ArrayList<TodoTask>();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_todo_list_manager);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstTodoItems);

        ad = new TodoAdapter2(this, R.layout.todoline_layout, tasks);


        list.setAdapter(ad);

        registerForContextMenu(list);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //Inflate the menu. this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.todo_list_manager_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //What happens when we click the menu.
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); //To hide keyboard after addition.
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS); //To hide keyboard.
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menuItemAdd){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddNewTodoItemActivity.class); 
            Log.w("Proc", "Before start");
            startActivityForResult(intent, BROWSER_ACTIVATION_REQUEST);

        }
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menuAbout){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ABOUT ME", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        int pos = info.position;
        TodoTask title = tasks.get(pos);
        menu.setHeaderTitle(title.getTask()); //set title for delete menu.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context, menu);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent input) {
        Log.w("PROC", "REturn");
        // if the results is coming from BROWSER_ACTIVATION_REQUEST 
        String newTask;
        if (requestCode == BROWSER_ACTIVATION_REQUEST) {

            // check the result code set by the activity
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if(input.hasExtra("Task") && input.getExtras().getString("Task") != null){
                    newTask = input.getExtras().getString("Task");
                    int day = input.getExtras().getInt("Day");
                    int month = input.getExtras().getInt("Month");
                    int year = input.getExtras().getInt("Year"); 
                    TodoTask todoLine = new TodoTask(day, month, year, newTask);
                    newTask += day;
                    newTask += month;
                    newTask += year;
                    tasks.add(todoLine);
                    ad.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Log.w("--------------", "UPDATED"); 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        int id = info.position;
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menuItemDelete){
            String itemToDelete = tasks.get(id).getTask();
            tasks.remove(id);
            ad.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item: [" + itemToDelete + "] was successfully deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution is to place an onClickListener inside your adapter

```
final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)    holder.status;
cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (cb.isChecked()) {
                    holder.task.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    holder.date.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                } else {
                    holder.task.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    holder.date.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but i have an issue with this answer, it wants me to make holder final, and then i can't split the flow inside the adapter. (if(localView == null), else). Do you have a suggestion how to solve this?

Comment: One more issue: now when I delete a row the checkbox "jumps" to the next row... I couldn't find a way to fix that... Please help!

Comment: Can you make a new question and supply code? I don't know what you mean really and writing code in comment is not easy to read!

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, i created new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472913/android-costume-layout-with-checkbox-in-listview-when-i-delete-a-line-if-it-wa